# How to initialise nested struct

Tags: go, struct, nested

I'm trying to initialise this nested struct without success. Can anyone help me?

```
type ResultQuery struct {
    Result []struct {
        Process `json:"processes"`
        Project     `json:"project"`
    }
}

type Project struct {
    Units struct {
        Distances string `json:"distances"`
    } `json:"units"`
    Name         string        `json:"name"`
}

type Process struct {
    Status       string `json:"status"`
    StatusEvents []struct {
        Time     int64  `json:"time"`
    } `json:"status_events"`
    ID              string        `json:"_id"`
    Type       string `json:"type"`
    Parameters struct {
        Project string `json:"project"`
    } `json:"parameters"`
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialize a nested struct in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809235/initialize-a-nested-struct-in-golang), [Initialize nested struct definition in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866879/initialize-nested-struct-definition-in-golang/26867130)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialize nested struct definition in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866879/initialize-nested-struct-definition-in-golang)