# Initializing a struct with an array

Tags: go, struct

The struct of interest is shown below

```
type rect struct {
width, height float64
testArray []struct{
    id    string
  }
}
```

I am trying to initialize the struct as shown below

```
r := rect{
    width: 10,
    height: 10,
    testArray: []struct{
        id: "wwwww",
    }, 
    {
        id: "wwwww",
    },
}
```

However it throws me an error saying

> syntax error: unexpected :, expecting type

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initialize nested struct definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866879/initialize-nested-struct-definition)

Comment: You will have a much easier time if you just give your type a name.

Comment: Thanks @Peter that actually helped me get a better understanding of how structs works in Golang. I was trying to initialize the struct as I was trying to write tests for an API. However, I ended up using a json config file for populating the data after, as that seemed more optimum. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
type test struct {
   id string
}

type rect struct {
   height float64
   width float64
   testArray []test
}

func main() {
   r := rect{
      height: 10,
      width: 10,
      testArray: []test{
         {id: "April"},
         {id: "March"},
      },
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse the better fix would be to explicitly declare `struct{id string}` but the initial implementation isn't too bad either.

On your declaration you have
`testArray []struct{id string}` where `struct { id string }` is your inline type.
So only thing you were missing was a an extra braces and re-declaration of the inline struct:

```
r := rect{
    width: 10,
    height: 10,
    testArray: []struct{ id string} { // re declare the inline struct type
      { id: "April" }, // provide values
      { id: "March" },
     },
}
```